# how to write a XML data 2 Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml

the snippt shows the XML detail : please referes to the image, shows the table...

```html
<ExtractSummaryDateSet>
      <_date>2017-09-20</_date>
      <_portfolioSummaries>
        <ExtractSummaryDateSetDetail>
          <_portfolioName>52613661_CL</_portfolioName>
          <_detail>
         
            <Before>0</Before>
            <After>-329</After>
            <ChangeMaturing>0</ChangeMaturing>
            <ChangeNew>-329</ChangeNew>
            
           
          </_detail>
        </ExtractSummaryDateSetDetail>
        <ExtractSummaryDateSetDetail>
          <_portfolioName>52613661_LP</_portfolioName>
          <_detail>
           
         
            <Before>0</Before>
            <After>-329</After>
            <ChangeMaturing>0</ChangeMaturing>
            <ChangeNew>-329</ChangeNew>
         
          </_detail>
        </ExtractSummaryDateSetDetail>
        <ExtractSummaryDateSetDetail>
          <_portfolioName>526136|Total</_portfolioName>
          <_detail>
         
            <Before>0</Before>
            <After>-329</After>
            <ChangeMaturing>0</ChangeMaturing>
            <ChangeNew>-329</ChangeNew>
            
           
          </_detail>
        </ExtractSummaryDateSetDetail>
```

I am trying to use 2 Dimential arrays in XML to create a table HTML

```
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
                  var row= x[i];
                  var date = row.getElementsByTagName("Date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        for(var j = 0;j < row.length; j++){

            var  before = row[j].getElementsByTagName("Before")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
            var  after = row[j].getElementsByTagName("after")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
    }
}
```

just wanna know is the example above semantically correct?
in the second array can i use row[j] to call the array

```
for (var y = 0; y < x.length; y++){


for (var i = 0; i < x[i].length; i++){

    table_summary +="<th></th><th></th><td>" + x[y][j].getElementsByTagName("_date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td>" ;

}
```

**how do I pass the value correctly? x[y][i] can't not find the value.**

[image]

Comment: can I request you put a sample of your XML on here?

Comment: and how are you paring your XML?

Answer (score 1):

I am working on XML format in web application and encounter to similar your issue. You can transform XML to HTML like your method but create HTML tags from XML is very cumbersome.

> I suggest you use [**XSLT**](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_client.asp) for this transform.

I created a simple `XSLT` for your XML and converted this transform very easily.

Please see **[Online transform](http://xsltransform.net/naZXpXU)** and click **html** in result panel to see HTML output for your XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a multi dimensional array as an array of arrays.

so this is fine :

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    var row= x[i]

    for(var j = 0;j < row.length; j++){
        var  before = row[j];
    }
}
```

However you can also write this as :

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0;j < x[i].length; j++) {
        var  before = x[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: yes  but it wouldnt work on Ajax / JS i call it like this   var  after = row[j].getElementsByTagName("after")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

Comment: have you tried debugging what you get back for each method call?
colsole.log(row[j]);
colsole.log(row[j].getElementsByTagName("after"));
etc.

Comment: my second loop return nth ... what is going to be the issue?

Comment: have you tried debugging row? is it actually an array?

Comment: I put down the XML file

Comment: just part of it, and there are multiple date and file names

Comment: error returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined

Comment: the line of  code :  x[i][j].getElementsByTagName("_date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue

Comment: do you have private skype? i can show you the whole code but not publicly lol

Comment: I got the result, but I couldn't get the lineup as shown in the image.

Comment: You parse your xml into a variable, what type of object is it? I suspect that you don't have a multi-dimensional array as your question suggests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155494/discussion-between-fenici-and-martinbyers).